# javascript alert and halting execution

Tags: javascript, html

Here we have a simple practice javascript game , it has a list of valid HTML colors, it picks a random color when the page is loaded , it asks you for guesses and gives you hints based on your input, when you enter the correct color , it changes the background color to the color of the answer.

when you enter the winning answer , you get an alert to tell you that you've won, for some reason the background color only changes after i press ok when the alert appears on the screen, even though the statement that changes the bg color precedes the alert.

My questions are:
  (1) why is the BG color changing after i close the alert popup ?
 (2)whats the correct way to make the BG color change before the alert appears on the screen?

```
function do_game() {
                var colors = ["aqua", "beige", "deeppink" , "coral",  "honeydew", "lime", "gainsboro","rebeccapurple","peru","tan"].sort();
                var answer = colors[Math.floor((Math.random() * colors.length))];
                var finished = 0;
                var numberOfGuesses = 0;
                var myBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];


                console.log(answer);
                while(!finished){


                var input = prompt('I am thinking of one of these colors \n\n' + colors + '\n\n what color am i thinking of? ' );
                if(input === null) 
                    finished = 1; 
                else{
                    numberOfGuesses++;
                    checkGuess(input);

                    if(input === answer){
                        myBody.style.background=answer;
                        finished = 1;
                        alert('You are right! \n you took ' + numberOfGuesses + ' Guesses!');

                    }
                }

            }

            function checkGuess(input){
                if(colors.indexOf(input) === -1){
                    //does not recognize input
                    alert('I don’t recognize that color!');
                }else if(input > answer){
                    //alphabetically higher
                    alert('Your input is alphabetically higher than mine!');
                }else if(input < answer){
                    //alphabatially lower
                    alert('Your input is alphabetically lower than mine!');
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't use `alert`. As you've seen it's blocking and there's no way to avoid that other than not using it.

Comment: as a side note, this seems to be browser-specific.  Firefox repainted before I closed the alert, but Chrome repainted after.

Comment: @andi lol i tried chrome and safari so i incorrectly assumed its universal, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The browser won't repaint the screen until the function which has updated the DOM has finished running.

`alert` is blocking, so prevents that function from continuing to run until you click OK.

Put the `alert` in another function and use `setTimeout` to call it in a non-blocking way.

```js
document.body.style.background = "blue";
setTimeout(function() {
  alert("Hello");
});
```